# apollo client cache persistance encrypted

Tags: react-native, apollo-client

I have a react native app that is using apollo client with cache persistance.

A security pen test report came back with references to the metadata that got intercepted on android with the apollo queries, showing as metadata...

So how to encrypt this cache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-cache-persist-encrypt

Comment: @manuelBetancurt were you able to use the package above?